# Сортировка linux

Tags: linux, shell

Имеется домашний каталог, который имеет директорию dir1, которая в свою очередь имеет множество файлов и каталогов, которые также множество каталогов и файлов и так далее. Есть задание:

> Рекурсивно подсчитать количество строк содержимого файлов из директории dir1, имя которых начинается на 's', отсортировать вывод по уменьшению количества, ошибки доступа не подавлять и не перенаправлять.

Моё решение

```sh
wc -l ~/dir1/s* */s* */*/s* ~/dir1/*/*/s* | gerp -v total | sort -r
```

Правильно ли оно? Не уверен что выводит то, что нужно, так как чтобы проверить нужно подсчитать вручную, что слишком долго из-за большего количества файлов.

Answer (score 1):

Ваше решение содержит три ошибки: нет рекурсивного обхода, `gerp` -> `grep`, `sort` не сортирует числа как надо.

Раз нужна рекурсия значит `find`.

```
find dir1
```

Каталоги нам не понадобятся, только файлы:

```
find dir1 -type f
```

Но и файлы нужны не все, а только `s*`. Кавычки нужны чтобы `bash` не делал автозамену:

```
find dir1 -type f -name 's*'
```

Считаем строки: `wc -l`. Считать нужно внутри `find`, для этого ключ `-exec`, который вставляет команду в команду. Понять это невозможно, но можно заучить: `'{}'` подставляет имя файла, `\;` завершает команду.

```
find dir1 -type f -name 's*' -exec wc -l '{}' \;
```

То что получилось надо отсортировать. `|` передаёт текст между командами, `sort` сортирует. Флаг `n` чтобы сортировать числа как числа, флаг `r` - сортировать задом наперёд:

```
find dir1 -type f -name 's*' -exec wc -l '{}' \; | sort -nr
```